no data being returned from Notion API call
Im using Notions API to print out some data from one of my own pages in notion and im using URLSession to make the request then parsing the unwrapped data but nothing is being returned to my console and I know my endpoint and API key is correct. I've gone through the notion API documentation can't can't seem to find anything in it that I am not doing or doing wrong. Ill provide my code as well as the documentation I've been consulting: https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro
''' 

import Foundation


struct Page: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String

    
}

let endpoint = URL(string: "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/8efc0ca3d9cc44fbb1f34383b794b817")
let apiKey = "… redacted …"
let session = URLSession.shared



func makeRequest() {
    if let endpoint = endpoint {
        
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { data, response, error in
            if let taskError = error {
                print("could not establish url request:\(taskError)")
                return
            }
            
            if let unwrapData = data {      //safely unwrapping the data value using if let
                do {
                       let decoder = JSONDecoder()                                 //JSONDecoder method to decode api data,
                       let codeUnwrappedData = try decoder.decode(Page.self,from: unwrapData)     //type: specifies its a struct, from: passes the data parmeter that contains the api data to be decoded
                } catch {
                    print("could not parse json data")
                }
            }
            
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    if let apiData = data {
                        print(String(data: apiData, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("unsuccessful http response:\(httpResponse)")
                }
                makeRequest()
            }
      
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

'''

Ive tried using the CFNetwork debugging tool but upon adding it into my environment variables and setting a value, nothing new appears or changes when I build my project.

To track down the problem, add this print("-->data: \(String(data: unwrapData, encoding: .utf8))") just before do{...}, and print("-->codeUnwrappedData: \(codeUnwrappedData)") just after let codeUnwrappedData = try ....
Note you are not using codeUnwrappedData.
Note also you should not call makeRequest() again in the makeRequest() function, remove it.
The important part is to have print("could not parse json data: \(error)") in the catch,
this will show you any errors you have. Note, you have to use your apikey in your request/url.

Try this example code to connect to your server and retrieve some data.
I don't have an apikey so I cannot test this, but the code should give you
some ideas.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                makeRequest() { results in
                    print("--->results: \(results)\n")
                    switch results {
                        case .success(let page):
                            print("-----> page: \(page)")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("-----> error: \(error)")
                        }
                }
            }
    }
    
    let endpoint = URL(string: "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/8efc0ca3d9cc44fbb1f34383b794b817")
    let apiKey = "YOUR-APIKEY"

    func makeRequest(completion: @escaping (Result<Page, Error>) -> Void) {
        if let endpoint = endpoint {
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
            request.addValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let taskError = error {
                    print("could not establish url request: \(taskError)")
                    completion(.failure(taskError))
                    return
                }
                if let unwrapData = data {
                    print("--->data: \(String(data: unwrapData, encoding: .utf8))\n")
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let codeUnwrappedData = try decoder.decode(Page.self,from: unwrapData)
                        print("--->codeUnwrappedData: \(codeUnwrappedData)")
                        completion(.success(codeUnwrappedData))
                    } catch {
                        print("could not parse json data: \(error)\n") // <--- important
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
   
}

struct Page: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}

If you get some errors while decoding the JSON response, look at the docs to ensure that your Page model match the json data.

seems similar what im doing, would it be better to make the api call in my contentview?

does my code work for you? If not, can you post the prints("---> data...") etc... and any errors you get.
